# What (if anything) does the Romulan Empire use for money?

Tags: star-trek, money, romulan

I've looked for what might be currency used by the Romulans, but couldn't find anything either on Memory-Alpha or any memories concerning TOS or any spinoffs- has anyone ever found something that might answer this question?

Comment: I agree there's not likely an answer.  TNG Unification when Picard and Data are in a Romulan Cafe the owner gives them the soup because she's highly suspicious.  Which would have been a rare opportunity to see payment.  "WOMAN: Doesn't matter to me. I don't know when he opens. Eat your soup, courtesy of a loyal establishment. Jolan tru."  Or they have perfect communism.

Comment: The only form of currency that I'm aware of in Star trek is gold pressed latinum

Comment: @SpacePhoenix- there are also Bajoran Litas, Klingon Darseks, Cardassian Leks, the Vlugta government uses a currency called an Isik.

Comment: @Nu'Daq - The Klingons also use Talons and the Federation have Credits.

Comment: @Nu'Daq that could be where the phrase "Isik for your thoughts" comes from (used a couple of times during Star trek: Discovery season 1)

Answer (score 4):

### TV/Film Canon

**We don't know.** As lucasbachmann has mentioned in a comment, we do know that they have some sort of exchange system because when Picard and Data visit a classy Romulan establishment in *TNG: Unification, Part I*, the owner gives them their meal for free because she thinks they're government stooges. Unfortunately, we don't get a mention of *what* they use for money, nor do we see it being used.

> **[SOUP WOMAN](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/208.txt):** *It doesn't matter to me. I don't know when he opens. Eat your soup. Courtesy of a loyal establishment. Jolan True.*

---

### EU Canon.

**Chains** (*[Takhse](http://mrklingo.freeshell.org/romulan/engtorihan.html)*<sup>∗</sup>) or **Marks**

Within the EU, we have a little more info to go on, particularly from the Diane Duane *[Rihannsu](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rihannsu)* novels, largely set on Romulus. There are umpteen mentions of "cash" and "money", often in relation to '***chains***' which appears to be interlinked rings of metal.

> Arrhae had once, very diffidently, made the suggestion, and had
> sparked a tirade of startling intensity for daring to presume that “a
> few dirty chains of cash” could buy the property that his ancestors
> had enriched with their blood.

and

> How I detest you! Ael thought as she went past the narrow, dark,
> cold-faced little woman. You would sell your sisters'-sons and
> -daughters to Orion slavers for a quarter-chain of cash if the deed would buy you power. No matter, though; you and yours will be rid of
> me soon enough. Ael stepped into the lift. "Ri'laefv'htaiell,
> Enarrain," she said, and waved the lift doors shut.

and

> she made off with as much haste as dignity and a full load of
> groceries permitted, leaving the man holding uncollected change from
> five full chains of cash and wondering what had happened to so
> suddenly increase House Khellian’s opinion of its own honor.

The in-universe history book [*Star Trek - Federation: The First 150 Years*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Federation_-_The_First_150_Years) suggests that whatever the Romulans use for cash has sufficient space to put a picture of their Emperor on.

> The portrait of Gileus I, which was used on Romulan currency

And *Star Trek Online* uses something called Romulan **[Marks](https://sto.fandom.com/wiki/Reputation:_New_Romulus)**. This seems pretty dubious as a source though, because a hecka lot of other races also seem to use them and the writers apparently just used them as a placeholder when they didn't have a set answer for the existing currency.

---

<sup>∗</sup> <sub>I have been unable to find the in-universe origin of this word (e.g. who invented it), but it does appear in most every version of the online Romulan Dictionary.</sub>